# Mongoid can not query non-latin attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

My Mongoid document has two attributes: `:en_name` and `ru_name`. I have created one model:

```
MyModel.create(en_name: 'sport', ru_name: 'спорт')
```

Then I query it:

```
MyModel.where(en_name: 'sport').first
```

It returns me my model.

When I try to query this:

```
MyModel.where(ru_name: 'спорт').first
```

It returns me `nil`

How to make Mongoid able to query attributes which are non-latin?

Comment: I have opened my MongoDB console by typing `mongo` command. Then I typed `use my_project_name`. Then I write your command and it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb uses UTF-8. However, you may experience problems if the server is running on Windows because Windows uses CP1251.
Use [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) (cross-platform graphical client) for that would make sure that the data has been written to the database in the correct encoding.
BSON can be encoded only in UTF-8. If the data is not displayed correctly, you probably are not converting your data to UTF-8 before uploading it to mongodb.

Check encoding `encoding_name = str.encoding.name`
Convert encoding `utf_str = Iconv.conv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', str)`

Comment: This site gives me 502 error. When I try to open it. I open it later

Comment: I checked my encoding of string that will be queried in Mongoid. It says that my encoding is already UTF-8

Comment: All right. I'll think about what else can be caused your problem.
By the way here's a good [article](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/documents/localized.html) about internationalization using mongoid.
Mongoid supports I18n  and requires minimal code writing for internationalization. Hopefully the article will be useful.